# Maven: copy dependency and its transitive jars into corresponding folder

Tags: java, maven, jar

Is there a way in Maven that for each dependency, we can copy its downloaded jars (Including transitive ones) into a folder that is named with the artifactId of that dependency?

For example, I have a dependency with artifactId `apple` that will download `a.jar, b.jar`, another dependency `banana` that will download `c.jar, d.jar`, how can I configure the pom.xml such that after I call `mvn dependency:copy-dependencies`, under `/target/dependency/`, those jars will be downloaded into its corresponding dependency folder.

For example, when you call tree dependency, you have this:

```
dependency/
├── apple
│   ├── a.jar
│   └── b.jar
└── banana
    ├── c.jar
    └── d.jar
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason for doing such things? You can use the appassembler-maven-plugin to create a repository under a definable folder....which will not create the folder structure you would like to have...

Comment: Basically I wanted to have an extension module that downloads optional dependencies so that I can choose to add any of them to the classpath. In this case, if I want to add `apple` dependency, I can put the path of `apple` folder into the classpath. With this structure, all the jars will be grouped into their corresponding dependency folder.

Comment: An optional dependency is usually not on the classpath so why do you need them? for testing? Furthermore your structure has the drawback if artifacts have dependencies which are used by two of your artifacts you have them duplicated in this kind of structure...I would suggest to make a separate module with the appropriate artifact `apple` as a usual dependency so you have it on the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

i think that is not possible. but you can write your own maven plugin that extends the dependency plugin to achieve this.

i think this should not be so complicated..

if i find the time, i will try this by myself... but i cannot promise it..

*Mojo Developer Cookbook*
http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook

*Othe Links:*

- https://maven.apache.org/guides/plugin/guide-java-plugin-development.html
- http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-custom-plugin.html